# Como quebrar linha no console do Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

estou inicando estudos em JAVA, e estou encontrando um probleminha no console do Eclipse, o mesmo exibe tudo na mesma linha, gostaria que houvesse uma quebra, alguém pode me ajudar? [Problema ocorrido](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GestC.png)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.